# navigate to another screen with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I an trying to navigate to another screen with StackNavigation, but I get an error telling me that navigation.navigate is undefined. This is my code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div data-snack-id="S1LJjR3a-" data-snack-platform="ios" data-snack-preview="true" data-snack-theme="light" style="overflow:hidden;background:#fafafa;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.16);border-radius:4px;height:505px;width:100%"></div>
<script async src="https://snack.expo.io/embed.js"></script>
```

Comment: In order to use the navigation prop, App itself must be contained within one of the Navigation stacks. My guess is that this component is not included in a route.

Comment: I don't see any code.  Post relevant code into the question.

Comment: Why is it tagged with react-native? I don't see react native components in your code. it seems its all react-js and not react-native